# Laravel 4 Setup: Driver [file] not supported

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to set up an existing site that was built using Laravel 4 on my server. I've gotten stuck at an error: Driver [file] not supported. It's throwing the error from Illuminate/Support/Manager.php.

I've tried using boilerplate Laravel files for the Manager.php file, as well as the SessionManager.php file, but it still won't work. I've also tried to figure out if file is registered as a driver, but when I try to insert the code for it, I get lost because of undeclared functions.

When I try to change the default session driver in app/config/session to anything else, it just throws other errors at me. Yet this is the same way the site was originally set up on its own server, so I don't understand why it isn't working. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 6):

I was stuck in same problem, solved it. After changing any configuration config cache must be cleared using `php artisan config:cache`. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

What is your **php version**?

Try to clean the session dir

```
app/storage/sessions
```

then try to clean autoload file

```
cd [YOUR LARAVEL ROOT DIR]
composer dump-autoload
```

and update composer package to be sure vendor folder is ok

```
cd [YOUR LARAVEL ROOT DIR]
composer update
```

Comment: try to clean the session folder and run the above command. Maybe some dependence are corrupted.

Comment: I've tried it, and it's telling me that there's nothing to update.